# Laravel Eloquent WhereIn 0 = 1

Tags: laravel, eloquent, where-in

I've trying to use a `whereIn` clause, but I get a rare behavior.

This is my relationship:

```php
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Role', 'system_users_roles', 'user_id', 'role_id')
    ->where(function ($query) {
        $query->where(function ($querypermissions) {
            $querypermissions->whereNotNull('service_id')
                ->whereHas('permissions', function ($q) {
                    $q->whereIn('app_id', $this->apps->pluck('id'));
                });
        })
            ->orWhereNULL('service_id');
    });
```

This code return some rows, but one is missing (the one I need, in this case).

If I change this line:

```php
$q->whereIn('app_id', $this->apps->pluck('id'));
```

To this one:

```php
$q->whereIn('app_id', [0 => 1]);
```

I get the correct result. I get the first result with the row I need.

I thought it was a problem of `$this->apps->pluck('id')`, because it could be empty but it isn't

I've tried with `$this->apps`, with `$this->apps->pluck('id')->toArray()`, but nothing works.

Can somebody told me what is wrong!?

More Info: When I shows the sql query (with `->toSql()`) it has :

```
bla bla bla...

and 0 = 1)) 

bla bla bla...
```

like saying **the array is incorrect**.

But, as I said before, I tried different ways to create an array with values to **whereIn**, but nothing works.

I read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30528573/multiple-where-in) but I need extra help.

Thank you!

Comment: Try `dd($this->apps->pluck('id'))` before the return statement in your relationship, what's the exact output?

Comment: The output is correct: `Collection {#534 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => 1
    1 => 2
  ]
}`

Comment: Okay now try passing the values hardcoded like `$q->whereIn('app_id', [1, 2]);` does that get the results you want?

Comment: Yes, yes. With this I got it. By I need dynamically. But I thing I found the problem... thank you, guy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.

`$this->apps->pluck('id')` is a relationship on the same model. And to any 'role' has differents values.

I changed the code, adding a variable with all apps I need:

```
$apps = Auth::user()->apps->pluck('id');
```

Now works fine.