# Laravel eager loading query where 0 = 1

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eager-loading

when I execute this code in Laravel 7.2.0

```
$news = NewsPost::select('title','slug','category_id', 'image', 'fulltext', 'created_at')->with('category:id,title,slug')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->simplePaginate(10);
```

I have 3 query on the page

```
select `title`, `slug`, `category_id`, `image`, `fulltext`, `created_at` from `news_posts` where `news_posts`.`deleted_at` is null order by `created_at` desc limit 11 offset 0
select `id`, `title`, `slug` from `news_categories` where `news_categories`.`id` in (2, 4)
select * from `news_categories` where 0 = 1
```

I cannot understand what is the purpose of last query and what means `where 0 = 1`

Comment: May be it's false statement for all time. That's why `where 0 = 1` use

Comment: What you mean under "false statement"?

Comment: Try the following:
`php artisan tinker`
`DB::enableQueryLog();`
`$news = NewsPost::select('title','slug','category_id', 'image', 'fulltext', 'created_at')->with('category:id,title,slug')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->simplePaginate(10);`
`DB::getQueryLog()`

See if that third query `select * from `news_categories` where 0 = 1` shows up.

Comment: yes. it is showing

Comment: Maybe this one helps you since it can better understand what i mean https://stackoverflow.com/a/6034021/9378077

Comment: not really helped

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30528708/3429323 probably your NewsPost contains a row eothout category, so laravel do this. Don't make sense for me, but reading this answers, you can understand why this happens.

Comment: did you find the reason / a solution. I have a similar issue

Comment: Any news here? @schel4ok